# Is "having a party" correct here?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

She's an employee of the law firm. **They were having an office party** when the man arrived and shot her.

Is "having" perfectly natural here to mean the law firm had a party and during that the man arrived?

Comment: Although it's a nuance, I would say that **people have a party/parties** (often meaning a good time) and that **firms/organisations hold parties**, which has a more formal edge. It's a fine call.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is perfectly correct.

Also:

> have a bath
>
> have lunch
>
> have a date
>
> etc.